# TCP server: How to keep server waiting for client connect

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am trying to build a simple TCP Server for my android app. Here is my code:

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread{
    int port;
    String result;
    ServerSocket serverClient;
    TextView tv5;
    MainActivity at;
    public TCPServer(int newPort,MainActivity at) {
        this.port=newPort;
        this.at=at;
        try{
            serverClient=new ServerSocket(port);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        tv5=(TextView)at.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Socket s;
        try {
            while (true) {
                s= serverClient.accept();
                BufferedReader inFromClient =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                this.result = inFromClient.readLine();
                tv5.setText(this.result);
                s.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
    public void setResult(String s){
        this.result=s;
    }
    public void TCPclose(){
        try {
            serverClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it calls when someone press the button:

```
receive_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    receiveResult.start();
                    tv5.setText(receiveResult.getResult());
            }
        });
```

But it seem that it can reach the line:

```
s= serverClient.accept();
```

It gets stuck before that line. I think that maybe there is no client connect to server so i try to write code for server to wait for the client but it does not work. Here is my attemp:

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread{
        int port;
        String result;
        ServerSocket serverClient;
        TextView tv5;
        MainActivity at;
        public TCPServer(int newPort,MainActivity at) {
            this.port=newPort;
            this.at=at;
            try{
                serverClient=new ServerSocket(port);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run() {
            tv5=(TextView)at.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            Socket s;
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(10)
                    s= serverClient.accept();
                    BufferedReader inFromClient =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    this.result = inFromClient.readLine();
                    tv5.setText(this.result);
                    s.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public String getResult() {
            return this.result;
        }
        public void setResult(String s){
            this.result=s;
        }
        public void TCPclose(){
            try {
                serverClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. Can someone show me where am i wrong. Thank you. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It reaches s= serverClient.accept(); and then it stopps?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt : It does not reach s= serverClient.accept(); , it stop before that code

Comment: Where exactly does it stop?

Comment: Does it hit your threadhandling method? What is receiveResult object?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt : receiveResult is TCPServer object, my code just stop before s= serverClient.accept(); (the android app has error:"Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: please tell where your code stop :)  Does it even it your thread handler method? please try .start .run or something else, Im not so sure. Please make sure if it hits your run method. Give me more information please  :)please tell where your code stop :)  Does it even it your thread handler method? please try .start .run or something else, Im not so sure. Please make sure if it hits your run method. Give me more information please  :)